# We need to write the FAQs

Tags: discussion

It's been a long time. We need to get started on those [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)s because it's way overdue. So how about this?

1. Post an answer with some FAQ ideas.
2. If it seems worth the effort, post a question-answer pair that will form the FAQ. Tag it [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) and put a banner like this on the top so people don't post more answers to it:

   > This is a proposed [faq](/questions/tagged/faq); please discuss on [this question](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/add-me-please). This notice will be removed once we have completed the discussion.

   It might be a good idea to make it a community wiki, so other people can edit it.
3. Post a question on Meta about your FAQ proposal. If enough people seem to think it's a good idea it'll be added to the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) (after some improvements, most probably).

What problems do you see new users encountering? Post them in answers and we'll pick the best ones.